# rails redirect to same page but add subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

If a user is at

```
blah.com/items/index
```

how do I redirect them to

```
de.blah.com/items/index
```

in a way that will work for any page?  Right now I'm using

```
<%= link_to 'German', root_url(:host => 'de' + '.' + request.domain + request.port_string) %>
```

but that redirects them to de.blah.com.  How do I keep the rest of the url?  I'm using rails 3.

Answer (score 11):

Keep it simple:

```
redirect_to subdomain: 'de'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= link_to 'German', params.merge({:host => with_subdomain(:de)}) %>
```

in app/helpers/url_helper.rb

```
module UrlHelper
  def with_subdomain(subdomain)
    subdomain = (subdomain || "")
    subdomain = "" if I18n.default_locale.to_s == subdomain
    subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
    [subdomain, request.domain(tld_length), request.port_string].join
  end

  def url_for(options = nil)
    if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
      options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
    end
    super
  end

  def tld_length
    tld_length = case Rails.env
      when 'production' then 2
      when 'development' then 0
      else 0
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: or you can write: `params.merge({:subdomain => 'de'})` , but url_helper usually needed

Comment: this just joins subdomain + domain + port string right?  I want to keep the whole url.

Comment: No, with this you will get the whole url. Becouse you do this: params.merge(...) - keep current params with action and controller.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [subdomain-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu) plugin might prove to be useful, it is also available as a gem.

Comment: I'd rather not add a gem just for this, everything else works.